# Same metamask account with different blockchains

Tags: blockchain, metamask

I am learning blockchain by following blogs, youtube videos etc. and as expected,am confused with few things.

So in tutorials they create an account using metamask and then use same account for testing at many places, like alchemy, test networks like rinkeby network which can be configured in remix web IDE etc.

I understand metamask is just an interface to work with different blockchains.
But how come same account created using metamask works fine with different blockchains?

I am surely missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metamask is an interface to use your private keys. The algorithm used to create addresses by different ETH compatible blockchain is same for a given seed combination. So they all give the same address.

Hope what i said makes sense.